# block back button for ceratin activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities A and B. What I want is to show activity A as an intro, the user will be unable to navigate back to it. Is there some flag I can set to activity A to do this? Can I block the back button for one activity only? Activity A is of course my main activity which automatically starts activity B after some "hard work".

Best regards.

Answer (score 5):

you do not need to block the back button, but just call finish() on your A activity after firing an intent to start B. Back button pops the previous activity from activity stack and it won't be able to pop A if it is already finished.

Answer (score 1):

For this you don't need to block the Back button. Simply, start the second Activity and quit the first one. And now if user presses the Back, they will be taken to the Android home screen not on your apps home screen.

Updates: By the way if you want to intercept the Back button for any reason, simply override the onBackPressed() method of Activity class. [See this for details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

Never override the functionality of a hardware button.

You should call `finish()` in `Activity` A right after starting `Activity` B (calling the `Intent`).

Answer (score 1):

it works but the application terminates and i'm redirected to  android's applications screen. I would like to stay in activity B if back button is pressed, i don't want to exit the app. here's is what i got :

```
public void startProgram(Context context){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```